# Server default not found on columns in MSSQL

Tags: sqlalchemy

I ran the inspector on a table that has known default constraints but no results are showing up from the inspector.  Is this some kind of issue with MSSQL dialect?  I can see indexes and primary keys using the inspector.

```py
from loguru import logger
import sqlalchemy as sa

logger.debug("begin engine create")
engine = sa.create_engine(DB_URI)

logger.debug("begin engine inspection")
insp = sa.inspect(engine)

logger.debug('list columns with default value')
columns = insp.get_columns(my_table_name)
[print(c["default"]) for c in columns if c["default"]]

logger.debug('index list')
indexes = insp.get_indexes(my_table_name)
[print(i) for i in indexes]

logger.debug(f'{my_table_name} PK')
pk_constraint = insp.get_pk_constraint(my_table_name)
print(pk_constraint)
```

Comment: Answered on GitHub [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/6553).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/6554#discussioncomment-799571

My issue was the user I was connecting with did not have table definition permissions.